# Streaming job failure-State Schema not Compatible issue

Tags: apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

My streaming job is now failing with the below error, streaming job worked fine for almost 2 months, and it is completely stateless transformation and just needs to append the new rows to the destination delta table. Before streaming, I'm manually providing the schema to a csv files, even verified the streaming job schema and downstream table schema both matches perfectly along with the datatype.

Not sure, why even in the stateless transformation, I'm getting the below error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
File "/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 2442, in _call_proxy
return_value = getattr(self.pool[obj_id], method)(*params)
File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 195, in call
raise e
File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 192, in call
self.func(DataFrame(jdf, self.sql_ctx), batch_id)
File "<command-422857213447422>", line 2, in write_to_managed_table
print(f"inside foreachBatch for batch_id:{batchId}, rows in passed dataframe: {micro_batch_df.count()}")
File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 670, in count
return int(self._jdf.count())
File "/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
return_value = get_return_value(
File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 110, in deco
return f(*a, **kw)
File "/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o433.count.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 28 in stage 13792.0 
failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 28.3 in stage 13792.0 (TID 752198) 
(10.139.64.13 executor 45): 
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.StateSchemaNotCompatible: Provided schema 
doesn't match to the schema for existing state! Please note that Spark allow difference of 
field name: check count of fields and data type of each field.
```

Answer (score 0):

There might a problem with the CSV file, it could be corrupted.
You can ignore this csv file by setting the "mode" option to "PERMISSIVE" or "DROPMALFORMED".

mode (default PERMISSIVE): allows a mode for dealing with corrupt records during parsing.
PERMISSIVE : sets other fields to null when it meets a corrupted record. When a schema is set by user, it sets null for extra fields.
DROPMALFORMED : ignores the whole corrupted records.
FAILFAST : throws an exception when it meets corrupted records.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/streaming/DataStreamReader.html#csv(path:String):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

```
spark.read.format("csv")
.option("header,"true")
.option("path","your.csv")
.option("mode","DROPMALFORMED")
.schema(csvSchema)
.load()
```